# Can't connect to Heroku postgres DB using Sequelize / NodeJS as missing sslmode tag

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js, digital-ocean

I'm playing with Heroku / DigitalOcean ("DO") App hosting services, trying to simply connect my NodeJS app to a Heroku/DO database. These services populate my environment variables with the following:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://username:password@url:ip/dbname?sslmode=require"
```

Unfortunately, when I'm running Sequelize, I get the following error message:

```
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[my ip address]", user "[db user]", database "[db name]", SSL off
```

I think the connection string might be misconfigured as I can clearly see it's trying to connect over ssl.

```
$ node -v
v15.9.0
```

Comment: Not all drivers support all elements of the DB URL.  As far as I can tell, the usual node.js driver does not support that way of specifying sslmode.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i share my connection with Digital Ocean DB PostgreSQL cluster

```
production: {
     host: process.env.DB_HOST,
     port: process.env.DB_PORT,
     database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
     username: process.env.DB_USER,
     password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
     dialect: 'postgres',
     dialectOptions: { 
     ssl: { 
         require: true,
         rejectUnauthorized: false
       }
     }
 }
```